# CAS Server .Net Client integration with asp.net web application Single Sign Out

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tomcat7, cas

i setup CAS SERVER for single sign up with asp.net web application and apache Tomcat 7. i follow below link to create configuration.

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+CASifying+ASP.NET+WebApp+-+ExampleWebsite

**My problem**

1. SSl Enable is not working(Import IIS .NET SSL Certificate to JVM). when i browse the cas server with `https://localhost:443/cas/index.jsp`. it gives the following error.

The webpage at `https://localhost:8443/cas/index.jsp` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 113 (net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH): Unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve the problem using following details. please follow each and every step given in the following links.

1. First Install tomcat

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Best+Practice+-+Setting+Up+CAS+Locally+using+the+Maven2+WAR+Overlay+Method

1. second About SSL Certification

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+CASifying+ASP.NET+WebApp+-+ExampleWebsite

if anybody has any problems, please feel free to contact me.